# Prevent message author from mentioning themselves with command Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Trying to prevent the user from mentioning themselves when they use the rob command. I tried `if message.author == user.mention` but it doesn't work.

```
   if message.content.startswith('!rob'):
        try:
            if message.author == user.mention:
                 await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} you cant rob yourself! ".format(message.author.mention))
        except:
            pass
        else:
             if get_dollars(message.author) < 0:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} you can't even afford a gun!".format(message.author.mention))
        finally:
            for user in message.mentions:
                if (get_dollars(user)) < 25:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} is too broke to rob ".format(user.mention))
                elif steal == 1:
                    print("{} catches {} slippin and sticks them up for ${} ".format(message.author.mention, user.mention, stealdollars))
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} catches {} slippin and sticks them up for ${} ".format(message.author.mention, user.mention, stealdollars))
                    remove_dollars(user, stealdollars)
                    add_dollars(message.author, stealdollars)
                elif steal == 2:
                    print("{} gets arrested trying to rob {} and has to post $250 bail ".format(message.author.mention, user.mention))
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} gets arrested trying to rob {} and has to post $250 bail ".format(message.author.mention, user.mention))
                    remove_dollars(message.author, 250)
                elif steal >= 3:
                    print("{} kicks {}'s door down but doesn't find any cash ".format(message.author.mention, user.mention))
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} kicks {}'s door down but doesn't find any cash ".format(message.author.mention, user.mention))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
if message.author in message.mentions:
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the question!

Answer (score 1):

message.author is a discord.Member, user.mention isn't.

Perhaps try something along the lines of:

```
if message.author.id == user.id: # User IDs don't change.
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You cannot rob yourself")
```

I hope this helped

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! I tried it but it allowed it to pass through and didn't send the message to the channel that I wanted it to. I also tried `message.author.id == user.mention.id` and it didn't send the message either.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm used to rewrite now, It was a mistake on my part. Forgot to add the channel argument lad.

Comment: I'm still not used to rewrite, I'll need to switch over soon. 
I used this but it seems like it's skipping right over it. Is my try/else/finally set up properly? I noticed when someone who has < 0 "dollars" that it will  send the "else" statement, but also send one of the "finally" statements.